# Task Parallel Library with QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I am looking some code where I see this code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(names, new ParallelOptions { TaskScheduler = { }, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, x =>
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(y =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", names[i++],
                               Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });
    });
```

My question is, Do we have any advantage using the QueueUserWorkItem inside the Parallel.ForEach?
For me it looks like we are creating 2 threads per each element, one in the ForEach and other in the QueueUserWorkItem.

Comment: No it doesn't makes sense. This will make the `Parallel.ForEach` to return before the operation completes, which may/may not be intended. Why would you write such code? I don't see any reason to use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` when you have `TPL`. btw you're not creating two threads per element necessarily.

Comment: I didn't write the code, it was written by someone else in this project. That's why I asked it here.I made a small test and noticed in this case the Parallel.ForEach doesn't have effect. If a client sends 6 jobs to the Service and the service picks up these 6 jobs and after this if other client sends other X tasks to the service, 
then the service won't be able to work in the X tasks of the last client until it finishes the 6 jobs of the 1st one. Am I right?

Comment: It is not clear what you man by job and service. To put it in a simple way: If you expect `Paralell.ForEach` to wait till all the code inside `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` then that's not what happening here. `Paralell.ForEach` here is simply waste. It calls `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and just returns **before** the code finishes execution.

Comment: That's perfect. How can I make your response as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't makes much sense. Main feature of `Paralell.ForEach` is that it executes the code in paralell and **waits** till all the code completes execution. This code defeats the purpose of `Paralell.ForEach`. It is better to ask the author what he intended.

What this code does is, It starts the paralell loop inside every iteration it queues the work to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and returns immediately. It will not wait till all the work completes.

Your code is no better than the following code. Almost equal to a simple foreach loop.

```
foreach(var name in names)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(y =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", names[i++],
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.